# Reading BMI270 IMU data with STM32F4 MCU

Tags: stm32, spi

I have a flight controller with a GYRO in it. The BMI270 is connected to SPI 1, and using STM32CubeIDE for the build, I am trying to read sensor data and send it via UART.

CHIP_ID = 0x24 is the value expected when requesting a read from 0x00. I can read it, but cannot read sensor data.

[image: BMI270 - flowchart - testing communication and initializing the device]

Source: [Sparkfun - Bosch BMI270 datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/9/a/2/9/6/bst-bmi270-ds000.pdf)

According to BMI270 datasheet, SPI can support two modes of operation, '11' (CPOL=1, CPHA=1) and '00'(CPOL=0, CPHA=0). In the below configs I am using the '00' mode.

[image]

```
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void BMI270_read_reg(uint8_t *reg, uint8_t *data, uint8_t len);
void uart1_transmit(uint8_t data);

// SPI_SCK 1 A05
// GYRO_CS 1 A04
// SPI_MISO 1 A06
// SPI_MOSI 1 A07
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();


  uint8_t spiData;
  uint8_t reg;
while (1)
  {
    BMI270_read_reg(&reg, &spiData, sizeof(spiData));
    uart1_transmit(spiData);
    HAL_Delay(500);
  }
/* USER CODE END 3 */
}

void uart1_transmit(uint8_t spiData)
{
    uint8_t data[30]="";
    sprintf((char *)data, "data read : %d\n", spiData);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, &data, sizeof(data), 100);
    HAL_Delay(100);

}
// rreg unused for testing purposes
void BMI270_read_reg(uint8_t *rreg, uint8_t *data, uint8_t len)
{
    uint8_t reg = 0x80 | 0x12;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &reg, 1, 10);
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, data, 1, 10);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

The code only transmits 0x00, do I really need to use interrupts to read IMU data ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need interrupts.

The internal modules on the chip are turned off by default after powerup.

You need to turn on the gyro before it starts measuring and reporting data for your code to read. Possibly additional configuration is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The picture below if from the datasheet you linked to. It looks like you have to enable the gyro because it is off after reset.

[image]